# jquery selector for dynamic html building is not working

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

I want to select span which is bild at run time using jquery 
Here's the resulted code

```
<div id="phases">
 <div>
    <span class="phaseTimer">test</span>
 </div>
  <div>
     <span class="phaseTimer">test</span>
 </div>
 <div>
    <span class="phaseTimer">test</span>
</div>
  <div>
 <span class="phaseTimer">test</span>
 </div>
</div>
```

I use this jquery selector inside `$.each` to select the span

```
   $("div#phases div:nth-child("+(index+1)+") span.phaseTimer").text("Not started yet");
```

here's the example I want to make , but the selector is not correct!
http://jsfiddle.net/jaVB9/3/

**EDIT**
Here's the scenario of the problem I face

http://jsfiddle.net/jaVB9/6/

Comment: It seems that you are calling the code before you inserted the HTML. That won't work. On the other side, I don't really see a reason for using a selector here. Just set the appropriate text when you create the elements. Using jQuery or pure DOM methods will make it a bit easier than string concatenation.

Comment: Also, including the div in `div#phases` is completely useless. `#phases` should be unique within the document.

Comment: @Andrew I read before that when using div@phases is much faster than #phases, is that right ?

Comment: @Felix Kling, I need to use a selector, please read the comment of the ShankarSangoli answer.

Comment: @Alaa: Then I suggest you provide a more complete demo. We can only work with what you give us. And no, `div#phases` is potentially slower.

Comment: @Felix Kling I update my question and add a link for my real problem. for using div#phases thanx for this information :)

Comment: Selectors are matched right to left. After finding an id, there is no point making sure it is a div.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is because you are trying to find the element before it is added to the DOM. I have fixed it in your fiddle take a look. Also you don't need a selector for that, you can just set the text while creating the required markup.

```
    var allPhases="";

    $.each(phasesData,function(index){
        var startDate = new Date(phasesData[index].startDate);
        var endDate = new Date(phasesData[index].endDate);

        if(phasesData[index].isCurrent=="true"){
            var elapsed_seconds =endDate-startDate;
            allPhases+="<div><span class=\"phaseTimer\">test</span></div>";
            setInterval(function() {
                elapsed_seconds = elapsed_seconds - 1000;
                $("div#phases div:nth-child("+(index+1)+") span.phaseTimer")
                .text(getElapsedTimeStrFormat(elapsed_seconds))
            }, 1000);
        }
        else if(phasesData[index].isCurrent=="false"){
            allPhases+="<div><span class=\"phaseTimer\">"+startDate+"</span></div>";
        }
    });


$("div#phases").html(allPhases);
```

http://jsfiddle.net/jaVB9/9/

Comment: Actually this is a snap shot of my code, I can't use this way because inside the span inside iscurrent condition there will be a call for timer and I will use setInterval() function,  this way cannot solve the problem.

Comment: If you should explain your actual scenario in the question then we will answer accordingly. Looking at your fiddle, I think this is the right way to do.

Comment: I see that. What is the issue in this?

Comment: Then The problem is that adding events before adding html to DOM, thank you :)